# Unity partial class does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 partial classes in main/editor projects unity, but unity show me error message "error CS1061: Type 'Engine.Test' does not contain a definition for 'radius' and no extension method 'radius' of type 'Engine.Test' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

./Assets/Test.cs (in main project):

```
namespace Engine {

    public partial class Test : MonoBehaviour {

        [SerializeField]
        private float radius = 1f;

    }

}
```

./Assets/Editor/TestEditor.cs (in project Editor):

```
namespace Engine {

    public partial class Test {

        private void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
            Gizmos.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 0f, 0.3f);
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(new Vector3(0,0,0), radius); // in "this" context field "radius" not found
        }

    }

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @vc74, sorry, yes, this typo, "Engine") | fixed

Comment: Why are you using the partial class? What are you trying to achieve?
 Maybe more of a comment for CodeReview as opposed to SO, but I'd argue that partial class definitions should only really be used for _separate_ pieces of logic. It seems like an obstacle having to jump from one partial to the other in order to understand them both.

Comment: @Eddge No, partial types can have different definitions so long as they are the same type (class) and are labeled partial. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)

Comment: @Sudsy1002 ahh thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unity Editor files are included in a separate C# project, and end up in a separate assembly. You cannot define partial classes over assembly boundaries.

Comment: It's clearly shown in the Solution Explorer too, you'll see `[ProjectName]` and `[ProjectName].Editor` as separate assemblies.

Comment: T_T, @PaulJan, can I divide classes in other ways?

Comment: It is very likely your usecase is best implemented as two separate classes. How *exactly* the two classes should communicate / interconnect depends very much on your exact usecase, You should probably ask a separate question asking that, but try to make it specific. 

Handwaving remark: you'll usually end up looking up behaviours by tag and/or using statics/singletons.

Comment: This applies to the editor. I want to move gizmos/editor-handler into the editor's code. But, i think simply i'll use #if. Thanks for you answer!